# What's a good way to save window/tab opening time now that Google Chrome has the battery saving feature?

Tags: javascript

Recent Google Chrome update might delete some necessary data: https://blog.google/products/chrome/new-chrome-features-to-save-battery-and-make-browsing-smoother/

In my case, I need to save when the current window/tab was opened. At first I was thinking to use `SessionStorage` to save that data, however from other posts here, I found out that this feature also cleans the session data, so if my code tries to save the window opening time:

```
let pageLoadTime = new Date();
sessionStorage.setItem("pageLoadTime", pageLoadTime);
```

It will be overwritten once the cleaning feature kicks in, and update the date.

I can't even use `LocalStorage` with the URL as the key, since the same URL might be opened in a few places.

Is there any way I can still save the information of when the window was originally opened?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that you want to check when the current tab was opened, across reloads: ie. if you press the refresh button the time doesn't change but if you open the website in a new tab it does, is that correct?

Comment: No, in my case a refresh is a new time, because every refresh is a request to the backend that extends the backend session. So far I've been using `sessionStorage` but I think that's not reliable anymore because to my understanding, after some idle time, the `sessionStorage` is cleared

Comment: In that case, why can't you just store it in a variable? ie. what necessitates using some sort of longer term storage? FYI, sessionStorage is persistent through reloads & restores - in fact that's mostly the entire point of sessionStorage

Comment: I need it for each window so I'm not sure how to store it and keep track of which window/tab it was. Session storage is good, but I heard that it cleans itself after some idle time with the new chromium settings

Comment: I still don't see why you can't just store it in a variable, please explain to me why you can't just do that

Comment: So from what I understand, Google Chrome cleans the cache after some time which means the values of these variables/sessionStorage will be cleared. So if for example I set a timestamp in a variable or sessionStorage to be `let date = new Date()`, then after some time the browser will reload this code and update the timestamp, even though the window/tab was not closed, but it was idle. Then when a user returns, it won't be the original time, but the updated one

Comment: alright, I think I understand now - partly my fault for not following the link you sent. What you're saying is that you want a way to store stuff which is persistent through memory saver clearing your tab, but is different for different tabs, and doesn't change on reloads. If so, then you've got a bit of a problem, because at least from what I've read opening a tab that's been cleared by memory saver is essentially no different from closing and re-opening the tab. May I ask what you use case is? ie. what you're using the timestamp information for

Comment: ultimately you might just have to ask your users to add your website to the memory saver exclusions, which prevents memory saver from clearing specified websites. It is of course possible that there's some sort of feature I don't know about, so I'll look a bit more thoroughly; but unfortunately I think unless chrome develops a specific feature it's gonna be pretty hard to differentiate between the user closing the page and memory saver clearing the page.